# Is it valid to set "display: list-item" on <a> tag inside <ol>?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I just discovered the `display: list-item;` option in CSS, but I'm not sure on how to use it correctly. It works fine for me in Firefox using:

```
<ol>
    <a href="target.php" style="display:list-item;">TargetLink</a>
</ol>
```

But Eclipse tells me that it is not supposed to be used like that (warning: invalid location of tag a)

I tried without `<ol>` or with a `<div>` tag with `style="list-style-type: decimal;"` instead, but this way every entry is the `0`.

How `is style="display: list-item;"` supposed to be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `display: list-item` like this, also only `li` can be direct children of `ul` and `ol`

```css
.item {
  display:list-item;
  list-style-type: square;
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

```html
<p class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
<p class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
<div class="random">Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
<div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
```

Comment: Does this work properly with decimal instead of square?

Comment: You could use counter instead but then what is the point of `list-item` https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/508/

Comment: @RoiEX: Not in CSS2.1, since in CSS2.1 there's no way to define counters for list-style-type - you can only do that with counter(). This will change in css-lists-3 but there are no known implementations.

Comment: Thanks @nenad vracar will use that! Please add this to your answer

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not valid HTML.

> `<ol>` Permitted content: Zero or more `<li>` elements  -[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol)

And `display:list-item` is the default style on `<li>` tag. You don't need to set it again once the HTML gets corrected like below.

```html
<ol>
  <li><a href="#">TargetLink</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">TargetLink</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">TargetLink</a></li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

Inline styles are CSS, not HTML. They simply happen to be a way to specify CSS for an individual element through markup. But changing the display type of an HTML element doesn't change whether it is valid in the current context. An `a` element can never legally be a child of an `ol` element, even if it appears to render "correctly".

You can use `display: list-item` to make an element render like a list item without it actually being a list item (and in fact, `li` elements have this style by default in order to be rendered correctly). But you cannot use it to make an element that is not a `li` element be a valid child of an `ol`.

You cannot currently use `display: list-item` with ordered list-style-types with arbitrary elements as only the `ol` element reliably supports list numbering out of the box, and CSS2.1 doesn't provide a way to create custom list counters with `display: list-item`. This will change in css-lists-3, but it's still at least a couple of years off.